a two steps expansion
I defined command \a and \b in the following code. Expanding \a just need one step and \b should take two steps. How to expand \b only using \expandafter ?
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}

\def\a{12}
\def\b{\a}

\expandafter{\a}

\expandafter\ifstrequal\expandafter{\a}{12}{True}{False} % % output is True

\expandafter\ifstrequal\expanded{{\b}}{12}{True}{False} % output is True

\expandafter\ifstrequal\expandafter{\expandafter{\b}}{12}{True}{False}
% output is False

\end{document}


\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\ifstrequal\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\b}{12}{True}{False} But why do you want to do this

I want to know more about \expandafter.

isn't the third eg what you want ie only expand \b?

third eg used \expanded. I want to use \expandafter there.

sorry, I meant the fourth. if you only want to expand \b and not \a.

that's all right. thanks for your example.

Very easy:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}

\def\a{12}
\def\b{\a}

\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\ifstrequal
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\b}{12}{True}{False}
% output is True

\end{document}

Why? After the first \expandafter has done its work, touching and expanding the third, the fourth and the sixth, TeX remains with
\expandafter\ifstrequal\expandafter{\a}{True}{False}

on the input stream.

Maybe this helps, maybe not, but it is too long for a comment.
As has been said before, do NOT use \def unless you are certain the macro name is free or you intend to redefine it. I expect you will say that it is only for the example and you would not do it in a 'real' document, but that is not sufficient justification to do something so easily left undone, IMHO.

Habits tend to leak. That's why they're habits.
Other users of this site are likely to copy code without realising you 'wouldn't do it for real' into their very real documents.
You force people answering you to rewrite your code to avoid endorsing it.
It is an unnecessary, repeated and tiresome distraction from the questions you want to ask.


\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
\def\amacro{12}
\def\bmacro{\amacro}

\def\tempa{\amacro}\verb|\tempa| \meaning\tempa

\expandafter\def\expandafter\tempa{\amacro}\verb|\tempa| \meaning\tempa

\expandafter\def\expandafter\tempa\expandafter{\amacro}\verb|\tempa| \meaning\tempa

\def\tempa{\bmacro}\verb|\tempa| \meaning\tempa

\expandafter\def\expandafter\tempa{\bmacro}\verb|\tempa| \meaning\tempa

\expandafter\def\expandafter\tempa\expandafter{\bmacro}\verb|\tempa| \meaning\tempa

\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\def\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\tempa\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\bmacro}\verb|\tempa| \meaning\tempa


\end{document}



I already regret answering this question.

Never mind. Your answer is valuable for me.
